# How I can install feast on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes-helm, feast

I would like to install feast on Kubernetes with helm - I follow the steps on https://docs.feast.dev/v/master/getting-started/install-feast/kubernetes-with-helm

after the command

```
helm install --debug feast feast-charts/feast
```

```
Error: scheme "gs" not supported
helm.go:81: [debug] scheme "gs" not supported
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/getter.Providers.ByScheme
    /private/tmp/helm-20210204-99981-1f8vc0y/pkg/getter/getter.go:156
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/downloader.(*ChartDownloader).DownloadTo
    /private/tmp/helm-20210204-99981-1f8vc0y/pkg/downloader/chart_downloader.go:94
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*ChartPathOptions).LocateChart
    /private/tmp/helm-20210204-99981-1f8vc0y/pkg/action/install.go:675
main.runInstall
    /private/tmp/helm-20210204-99981-1f8vc0y/cmd/helm/install.go:185
main.newInstallCmd.func2
    /private/tmp/helm-20210204-99981-1f8vc0y/cmd/helm/install.go:120
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    /Users/brew/Library/Caches/Homebrew/go_mod_cache/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:850
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    /Users/brew/Library/Caches/Homebrew/go_mod_cache/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:958
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    /Users/brew/Library/Caches/Homebrew/go_mod_cache/pkg/mod/github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.1/command.go:895
main.main
    /private/tmp/helm-20210204-99981-1f8vc0y/cmd/helm/helm.go:80
runtime.main
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15.7_1/libexec/src/runtime/proc.go:204
runtime.goexit
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.15.7_1/libexec/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1374
```

helm version 3.5.2

how I can fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

seems you need to install gs helm plugin to download dependency from google cloud storage

helm plugin install https://github.com/ausov/helm-gs.git

Answer (score 0):

The problem you experienced above was related to this issue: https://github.com/feast-dev/feast-helm-charts/issues/2

It has since been resolved. You can now install Feast using the above commands **without** helm-gs. All you need is Helm